# Symlinks in vscode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, dependencies, package.json

This just might be a very dumb question but as I am new this so I am asking this.

How are the symlinks created?
Are they identified automatically in vs code? And even if I am giving a dependency version for the same in package.json in a Vue project how come on reinstalling dependencies it fetches the changes from the local folder linked by symbolic link and not from the npm module as specified in package.json.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dannielarriola.extlibraries

Then

in Windows: Shift-Ctrl-P
in OSX: Shift-CMD-P

then add the full path of the folder or file to be added to your project
and then the name of the symlink

Pls. include an online example or some further information about the npm question.